# Importing a Craft database error

Tags: database, mysql, import

I dumped from Craft my database from server A and am trying to install it to a fresh copy of Craft on server B.

I've got Craft up and running, and when I try importing my Craft SQL file in PHPmyAdmin, I get an error every time:

[image: craft error]

Is there something I need to setup in Craft regarding asset files before my import will work?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL exports only include the tables, not the database settings. You need to create a database first, open it and then import the tables.

Comment: I created a database on my new server, and then went to import the sql file into it, and still got this error.

Comment: The error says no db selected though.

Answer (score 1):

This caught me out too.

In PhpMyAdmin, click Databases tab, click the database you wish to import into, then Import tab.